# Does shotwell have no function to save a low quality version of a JPG?

Tags: shotwell, image-processing

It often happens that I have to scale down screenshots in quality for forums. If Shotwell does not have a function to do this, is there an application with this feature I could use?

Comment: If you use Shutter (free screenshot tool) - available from the Ubuntu Software Centre, will that not allow you to size the screen captures as required?

Comment: @NoviceUserFrance Sorry I mean the quality not screen size

Comment: Would saving a png as a jpeg not automatically convert it to a lower resolution? About better software: I tend to do this commandline with imagemagick tool "convert"

Comment: @Rinzwind On windows I used Irfanview which had such a function.

Answer (score 2):

Try GThumb.

```
sudo apt-get install gthumb
```

1. Open up your image.
2. Select save as in **File > Save as**
3. Give it a name with a `.jpg` extension.
4. Select the directory and click save.

This little window pops up where you can change the image quality by sliding the quality slider:

[image: JPG quality dialog]

Comment: Incredible that shotwell doesn't seem to have it (using 0.30.1 – “Celle”).

Answer (score 1):

**File > Save As**

Format: JPEG
Quality: Low(50%)
Scaling constraints: Original size/Width or height/Width/Height
(1200 pixels)

When you select the "original size" of JPG, you cannot change the resolution. Switch to "Width or height" for a while, then change the quality and then you can select the original size again, the selected quality will stay.

For scaling down images you can also define the size ("width" or "height") of the result in pixels.